# Angular unit test, como excluir archivo del coverage?

Tags: angular, typescript, pruebas-unitarias, karma-jasmine

Como puedo excluir ciertos archivos del coverage para que karma no los incluya?

Me esta pasando que tengo archivos (que no tienen un .spec) y que me afectan al coverage

por ejemplo mi app.module, **tiene 2 funciones** que son para redux (ngrx), con el tema de rehidratar al dar f5 etc, pero no las puedo testear y aun asi en el coverage me marca como que falta testear eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas funciones estan en el app.module, pero tambien tengo archivos sueltos que no tienen un .spec que tambien tienen otras funciones, salen en el coverage pero no las puedo testear

Hay forma de excluirlos?

O por ejemplo el siguiente archvio es un reducer y el coverage me lo marca completo que falta testearlo..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]